# how can i find the following string date format:"Monday on or before May 24 $Year" via DateTime strtotime

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

im trying to find Victoria Day. The holiday date is: "Monday on or before May 24"

im not able to find the correct formatting that DateTime can accept.

when i try to run this code i get an **fatal eror:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Monday on or
>   before May 24 2015) at position 7 (o): The timezone could not be found
>   in the database

```
if ($GYear >= 1845) {
                $VictoriaDay = new DateTime("Monday on or before May 24 $GYear", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
                $VictoriaDay_Day = $VictoriaDay->format('j');
                if ($GDay == VictoriaDay_Day) {
                    return "Victoria Day";
                }
            }
```

Any suggestiion please on how can i get this date via DateTime?
thianks!

Answer (score 1):

You are better using the [`\DateTime::modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) function. Something like this should suit:-

```
function getVictoriaDay($year = null)
{
    if(!$year){
        $year = (int)(new \DateTime())->format('Y');
    }
    $victoriaDay = new \dateTime("$year-05-24");
    if($victoriaDay->format('D') !== 'Mon'){
        $victoriaDay->modify('previous monday');
    }
    return $victoriaDay;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/GsblDt)

Comment: thanks.that worked for me! but  after some thought... i find that i can use the sentence "$victoriaDay = new DateTime("previous monday $GYear-05-25", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
"

Comment: @codingnighter2000 I'm surprised that works, but [it does!](https://3v4l.org/abJfq). Well done :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
function victoria_day() {
    $t = strtotime('May 25');
    return $t - (date("N")-1)*24*60*60;
}
```